# Unable to find 'at/htlpinkafeld/wps/Wps/gwt/xml.gwt.xml' on your classpath

Tags: java, gwt

I am working on an `GWT-App` but I have a problem when I try to compile the application.

Eclipse says:

```
at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml
      Loading inherited module 'at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'at/htlpinkafeld/wps/Wps/gwt/xml.gwt.xml' on 
         your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a 
         classpath entry for source?

[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

Here is my `Wps.gwt.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  When updating your version of GWT, you should also update this DTD reference,
  so that your app can take advantage of the latest GWT module capabilities.
-->
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.5.1//EN"
  "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/2.5.1/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<module>
<!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
    <inherits name='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'/>

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class.  -->
    <entry-point class='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.client.Wps'/>

    <!-- servlet context - path is arbritray, but must match up with 
         the rpc init inside java class. Tomcat will listen for this 
         from the server and waits for rpc request in this context -->
    <servlet class="at.htlpinkafeld.wps.server.MySQLConnection"
        path="/MySQLConnection" />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome"/>
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark"/>
</module>

<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
<source path='client'/>
<source path='shared'/>
```

Where did I make the mistake?

Comment: This line is the culprit: `<inherits name='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'/>`; what do expect it to do?

Comment: I just tried it because i saw it on the net. When i erase that line the following error appears. Checking for new version at http://tools.google.com/webtoolkit/currentversion.xml?v=2.5.1&id=141e3ebe19a&r=releases/2.5@11546&e=DevMode
      Loading inherited module 'at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'at/htlpinkafeld/wps/Wps/gwt/xml.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

Comment: Have you tried this: <inherits name='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps'/>

Comment: When i do that i get the following error message from eclipse WARN] Unable to process 'file:/C:/Users/Stefan/workspace/wps/war/WEB-INF/web.xml' for servlet validation
then a lot of unknown sources and thenading inherited module 'at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'at/htlpinkafeld/wps/Wps/gwt/xml.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method

Answer (score 0):

First as Thomas and El Hoss said in the comments, the line `<inherits name='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps.gwt.xml'/>` should be `<inherits name='at.htlpinkafeld.wps.Wps'/>`.

Second. the tag `<servlet...>` is very restricted and possible not something you can or want to use. Here is what the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html) says about the servlet tag:

> The  element applies only to GWT's embedded server
>   server-side debugging feature.
>
> NOTE: as of GWT 1.6, this tag does no
>   longer loads servlets in development mode, instead you must configure
>   a WEB-INF/web.xml in your war directory to load any servlets needed.

So you need to set the servlets configuration in the web.xml or (depending on the version of the server) you can use the [@WebServlet](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation instead of the `servlet` in gwt module file.